# logout redirect with Websphere Liberty OIDC provider

Tags: redirect, logout, openid-connect

As a RP, want to request the Websphere liberty OIDC provider to redirect to a url post logout. How to achieve that?

What parameters in the logout request needs to be passed?

Answer (score 0):

Liberty supports openid connect session management, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_oidc_session_mgmt_endpoint.html